# Parse XML with class information and instantiate via Reflection

Tags: java, xml, dom, reflection, xml-parsing

I have two XML Files that contain information about some classes. After parsing the XML i want to instantiate these classes via Reflection.

I parse the xml with DOM and Recursion. What i want to know is which is the most generic way to implement it. Which is the optimal way to transfer the information and build the GUI.

I really cannot think anything else expect many IF...ELSE(
like this:

`if (node.getNodeName() == "class") {
      Class cls = Class.forName(node.getNodeValue());
}`
)

statements but i do not think that this is the optimal way.

The dom parser:

```
 for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) {

        Node tempNode = nodeList.item(count);

        // make sure it's element node.
        if (tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            // get node name and value
            System.out.println("\nNode Name =" + tempNode.getNodeName() + " [OPEN]");
            System.out.println("Node Value =" + tempNode.getNodeValue());

            if (tempNode.hasAttributes()) {

                // get attributes names and values
                NamedNodeMap nodeMap = tempNode.getAttributes();

                for (int i = 0; i < nodeMap.getLength(); i++) {

                    Node node = nodeMap.item(i);
                    System.out.println("attr name : " + node.getNodeName());
                    System.out.println("attr value : " + node.getNodeValue());
                    //    System.out.println("Node Value : " +);
                    if (node.getNodeName() == "class") {
                        Class cls = Class.forName(node.getNodeValue());
                    }
                }

            }

            if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {

                // loop again if has child nodes
                printNote(tempNode.getChildNodes());

            }

            System.out.println("Node Name =" + tempNode.getNodeName() + " [CLOSE]");

        }
```

The XML files looks like this:

```
<ui-model>
<waui>
    <abstract-container wauiId = '1'>
        <abstract-button wauiId = '2'></abstract-button>
        <abstract-button wauiId = '3'></abstract-button>
        <abstract-button wauiId = '4'></abstract-button>
    </abstract-container>
</waui>
<wrm>
    <wr-item wauiId = '2'>
        <abstract-properties>
            <abstract-property name='text'>Button1</abstract-property>
        </abstract-properties>
        <polymorphic-properties>
            <polymorphic-instance piId='swingRectButton'>
                <polymorphic-property name='width'>100</polymorphic-property>
                <polymorphic-property name='height'>50</polymorphic-property>
            </polymorphic-instance>
            <polymorphic-instance piId='swingRoundButton'>
                <polymorphic-property name='radius'>80</polymorphic-property>
                <polymorphic-property name='background-color'>red</polymorphic-property>
            </polymorphic-instance>
        </polymorphic-properties>
    </wr-item>
    <wr-item wauiId = '3'>
        <abstract-properties>
            <abstract-property name='text'>Button2</abstract-property>
        </abstract-properties>
        <polymorphic-properties>
            <polymorphic-instance piId='swingRectButton'>
                <polymorphic-property name='width'>200</polymorphic-property>
                <polymorphic-property name='height'>60</polymorphic-property>
            </polymorphic-instance>
        </polymorphic-properties>
    </wr-item>
    <wr-item wauiId = '4'>
        <abstract-properties>
            <abstract-property name='text'>Button3</abstract-property>
        </abstract-properties>
        <polymorphic-properties>
            <polymorphic-instance piId='swingRoundButton'>
                <polymorphic-property name='radius'>9</polymorphic-property>
                <polymorphic-property name='background-color'>blue</polymorphic-property>
            </polymorphic-instance>
        </polymorphic-properties>
    </wr-item>
</wrm>
```

```
<widget name='abstract-button'>
<abstract-properties>
    <property name='text' id='wsl_1'/>
</abstract-properties>
<polymorphic-instances>
    <instance name='swingRectButton'>
        <polymorphic-properties>
            <property name='width' />
            <property name='height' />
        </polymorphic-properties>
    </instance>
    <instance name='swingRoundButton'>
        <property name='radius' />
        <property name='background-color' />
    </instance>
</polymorphic-instances>


<polymorphic-instances-api>
    <polymorphic-instance id='swingRectButton' class='javax.swing.JButton'>
        <property name='text'>
            <native-method>setText</native-method>
            <param-type>String</param-type>
        </property>
        <property name='width'>
            <native-method>setWidth</native-method>
            <param-type>Integer</param-type>
        </property>
        <property name='height'>
            <native-method>setHeight</native-method>
            <param-type>Integer</param-type>
        </property>
    </polymorphic-instance>
    <polymorphic-instance id='swingRoundButton' class='gr.epp.aswing.RoundButton'>
        <property name='text'>
            <native-method>setLabel</native-method>
            <param-type>String</param-type>
        </property>
        <property name='radius'>
            <native-method>setRadius</native-method>
            <param-type>Integer</param-type>
        </property>
        <property name='background-color'>
            <native-method>setBackgroundColor</native-method>
            <param-type>String</param-type>
        </property>
    </polymorphic-instance>
</polymorphic-instances-api>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about writing this as a comment to your question, but after more thought, I think it is an appropriate answer.

**Avoid premature optimization.**

If you've already written code that works and you're running into a specific problem then explain that problem. But you should not try to optimize your code unless there is an identifiable problem with it.

See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization